# Selenium click absolute element out of view

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i have an selenium test for an Primefaces Website

I want to select a item in a combobox

when i click the combobox with selenium it creates an absolute positioned list, where i want to click an item.

But the list is positioned absolute out of the screen (because the combobox is scrollen on the bottom of the screen)

now i want to click an item

```
driver.findElement(element).click();
```

but the click gets an timeout

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

when moving the item into view with firefox (hit F12, locate element, change top-css-value to 0) the test continues correctly

any idea how to click such an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found a working solution

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(element));
```